# Error trying to get title attribute in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm a bit stumped on why this isn't working. I'm trying to get the title of a document that's loading in the browser. Unfortunately my code is producing a weird error.

```
let lg = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);

window.addEventListener("load", function p7Foxload() {

    window.removeEventListener("load", p7Foxload, false);

    gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
        if(event.originalTarget instanceof HTMLDocument) {
            lg.logStringMessage(event.originalTarget.getAttribute('title'));
        }
    }, false);

}, false);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
event.originalTarget.getAttribute is not a function
```

I don't understand why it's saying the getAttribute method is not a function.

Comment: A document doesn't have attributes - only elements do. I guess that you were trying to get the document title in which case the answer by @MaxArt is the correct one. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because a `HTMLDocument` just doesn't have it. Use `event.originalTarget.title` instead.